# Не запускается активити по вызову

Tags: java, android, sqlite, activity

Хочу написать простой менеджер паролей для тренировки работы с базой данных. Но не могу смотреть на уже добавленные записи на базу. Код этого класса:
ViewPasses.java ---

```
    import android.database.Cursor;
     import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
     import android.widget.TextView;

 public class ViewPasses extends ActionBarActivity {

private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_passes);

    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);
    mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("yourpass", new String[]{DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN,
                    DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN},
            null, null,
            null, null, null) ;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String website = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN));
    String login = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN));
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN));

    TextView infoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    infoTextView.setText("Sayt" + website + " Login " + login + " parol " +
            password );
    cursor.close();
```

} 
}

При вызове из MainActivity появляется сообщение "Приложение остановлено" и закрывается.
что я делаю неправильно? Тестил программу на реальном девайсе под Андроид 5

StackTrace из Android Studio

```
02-02 22:09:28.211 4055-4055/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.nagizade.whatismypass, PID: 4055
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nagizade.whatismypass/com.nagizade.whatismypass.ViewPasses}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                              Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
                                                 at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
                                                 at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                 at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                                                 at com.nagizade.whatismypass.ViewPasses.onCreate(ViewPasses.java:28)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: стектрейс ошибки приложите

Comment: @temq стек что?

Comment: То, что выводится в логи, т.е. сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Это то что выводится красным в logcat в момент когда появляется сообщение об остановке приложения

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  спасибо за информацию. добавил стектрейс

Comment: @temq спасибо за информацию. добавил стектрейс

Comment: Ну судя по ошибке ваш запрос в базу возвращает 0 записей, а вы не проверив есть ли записи пытаетесь читать столбцы из несуществующей  первой записи

Comment: @xkor тогда у меня проблема с записем на базу? но при записе ошибки не появляются.

Comment: @RedShaman, если вы уверены, что записали данные в базу, возьмите ее с устройства и проверьте реально ли там есть добавленные вами строчки. На счет кода, я понимаю, что вы хотите считать хотя бы одну запись, но вы работаете с курсором, а это набор записей, который может быть пустым. Используйте такой код: `while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {
    result = cur.getString(0);
    cur.moveToNext();
   }
   if(cur != null){cur.close();  cur = null; }`
И обязательно закрывайте курсор и прочее....